# Calculate the total amount of cache being used in all apps android?

Tags: android, caching

I want to know the total amount of cache being used by all apps in adroid, any suggestions?

Comment: This link will help you: [How to discover memory usage of my application in Android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hope this help you*

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
        System.out.println("Available Memory : " + memoryInfo.availMem);
        System.out.println("Thresold Memory : " + memoryInfo.threshold);
        System.out.println("Total Memory : " + memoryInfo.totalMem);
```